# Update an XML File with child node using vb.net

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

Following is the "by default" structure of my xml file I'm starting with it: The number of `<Group>` is ten

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<!--Properties General Logistic Plan-->
<Groups>
<Group id="01" GroupLevel="01" Description="First Group, Category first">
  <subGroups>

  </subGroups>
</Group>
<Group id="01" GroupLevel="02" Description=" First Group, Category second ">
  <subGroups>

  </subGroups>
</Group>
………
</Groups>
```

What I want is to pass a new child named: subGroup
In “01”Group
`<subGroup id=”x” GroupLevel=”01.01” Description=”blablabla”/>` 
Or additionally in “02”Group
`<subGroup id=”z” GroupLevel=”01.02” Description=”blablabla”/>` 
More over I have to create a new `<Group>` under the `<subGroups>` (depending from the `GroupLevel`) and the final structure will be looks like that:

```
<Groups>
<Group id="01" GroupLevel="01" Description="First Group, Category first">
  <subGroups>
    <subGroupB id=”10” GroupLevel=”01.01” Description=”blablabla”/>
      <GroupA id="21" GroupLevel="01.10" Description=" blablabla ">
         <subGroupC id=”10” GroupLevel=”01.21” Description=”blablabla”/>
        <GroupB id="33" GroupLevel="01.10.21" Description=" blablabla ">
            <subGroupD id=”12” GroupLevel=”01.10.21” Description=”blablabla”/>
        </GroupB>
      </GroupA>
  </subGroups>
</Group>
<Group id="01" GroupLevel="02" Description=" First Group, Category second ">
  <subGroups>

  </subGroups>
</Group>
………
</Groups>
```

The subGroups… B or C or D may be many and of course they have to passed each time in each own position.
 
I have already used multiple solutions for this; but no one fulfills my needs
This issue exceeds my personal programming experience
Is there someone who knows what I have to do?  
If you please give me a full solution using vb.net; something like `public class`.
It needs to be like that because the final user needs to add a new `subGroup` depending on the `GroupLevel` for each own customer use.

Comment: Can you list what you've tried and why it didn't work?

Comment: I didn't say that `didn't work` I say that what i receive not cover my expectations. I was use all what is around read and write for xml

Comment: Your example shows 2 groups with `id="01"`. Is that a typo or are your ids not unique within your xml?

Comment: The ID may be omitted. It is not important.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **XDocument** if you are using net framework3.5, here're some suggestions and you can continue to code and feedback;)

1) Please fetch out the specific node by XDocument's Descadents or Elements function, maybe it will be combined with First() or FirstOrDefault(). However, please first use XDocument's Load to load the full xml file, notice its path.

2) Then you can use XElment's Add method to add a new XElement (See MSDN sample: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.add(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

3) In the end, please use XDocument's Save method to override the xml file.

Comment: Yes XElement method... I use it but you see the issue here is to search the right position in order to insert the new line. I have the filling that the solution is not in `What method will use` but is `what work flow method we have in our mind` to solve it. I'm still searched

Comment: You can use Xdocument's Descedants("your xml node name here").Where(conditions……).First() or related lambda expression to define the node you are looking for.

Comment: I'll do that and see what is produced. Thanks. Keep in touch

Comment: Of course, just show us your codes and welcome your feedback about your errors , exceptions……

Comment: Be sure about that. Will follow by details